# CSS style resetting

Tags: css, css-reset

Usually in order to get the style the same for every browser you see some sites have something like this:

`html, body, div, span, object, ... {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}`

Is there a reason why they don't simply use:

`*, html { ... }`

Comment: What is `., html` supposed to mean?

Comment: I believe it means all tags. Edit: Its meant to be a asterix

Comment: @Ben: That would be `*` by itself. `, html` isn't needed either.

Comment: @BoltClock: Hmm, I've always put the `*,html` and never really thought about what it's actually doing, although I do remember (a long time ago) changing it to just `*` and it not working for some reason or another (possibly an Internet Explorer issue?)

Comment: @Ben: Weird. IE is alright with `*`, but if you had a separate rule for `html` it will override `*` on any browser.

Comment: @BoltClock <html> is an element, so you can style it with a background, for example (a good option, then you don't need a div#wrapper because it can be the <body>), so you can specify properties that are inherited by their children. And of course * override html, because * is the same as `h1,h2,...,div,...{}`

Comment: @Tae: Except `*` matches `html` too. `*` doesn't override `html`, it's the other way around.

Comment: @BoltClock that's true, but I'm sure if you try `html{...}` and below `*:not(html)` (a CSS3 selector) you see that * override the inherited properties with a tool like Firebug.

Comment: @Tae: That's because `:not(html)` is more specific than (and is mutually exclusive to) `html`. Nothing to do with `*`.

Comment: @BoltClock now I understand you, sorry, my English is not the best. I just try `p{...}` and below `html{...}` and the last rule don't override the first, so you are right: it's weird that `html{}` override `*{}`.

Comment: @Tae: It's OK. Actually, it's not weird at all because `*` is a general selector that means "anything". Something has to override it for CSS to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more broad a set of CSS rules is, the more processing it'll take to load them. The best ruleset is also the most specific.

Comment: `*` would also target elements like `<head>` and `<area>` and other tags that don't need styling.

Comment: To do a massive "CSS Reset" up front is just wasteful and redundant.  I'm a big proponent of simply resetting only the elements you need to reset.  Many elements are unused and some are already styled by your normal CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  ...
}
```

to reset everything, the big drawback is, it does exactly that. Then paragraphs don't have any spacing, etc. I'd rather have universal style than having no style and starting from scratch.

[This article](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) does a good job explaining the benefits as well, starting at the section titled "A reset to where it all started…"